# Crashing when using QJSValue call

Tags: qt, qml

I am getting crash within my JavaScript function quite frequently when I invoke the `QJSValue`s call function.

I have a thread that is running, calling a QMetaObject invokeMethod as a `QueuedConnection` rather than `DirectConnection` to ensure that the method will be called in the main ui thread. This method that is invoked will then subsequently trigger the `QJSValue` JavaScript function. The JavaScript function modifies some of the UI element within the QML. When there are no modification to the UI elements, I notice that there is no crash.

Is there any gotcha that I should take note of?

It is crashing after about 10hrs running on a Raspberry PI3.

> 1 ??
>   2 QV4::Object::call qv4object_p.h 372 0x765d5a8c
>   3 QJSValue::call qjsvalue.cpp 670 0x765d5a8c
>   4 ?? 0x70352fb8

This is a modified code from Chapter 6-plugins

PieChartWorker class

```
PieChartWorker::PieChartWorker(QObject *parent):
    QThread(parent)
{
}

void PieChartWorker::run()
{
    QString text;
    while(1) {
    QString textb = text.sprintf("The answer to the meaning of life is %i", std::rand()%100);

        QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this,
                                  "responseInternal",
                                  Qt::QueuedConnection,
                                  Q_ARG(QString, QString::fromLocal8Bit("hello")),
                Q_ARG(QByteArray, textb.toLocal8Bit()));
        QThread::msleep(50);
    }
}

void PieChartWorker::responseInternal(const QString question, const QByteArray& answer)
{
    emit response(question, answer, callback);
}

void PieChartWorker::registerCallback(const QJSValue callback)
{
    this->callback = callback;
    start();
}
```

PieChart class

```
PieChart::PieChart(QQuickItem *parent)
    : QQuickItem(parent)
{

    PieChartWorker* worker = new PieChartWorker();
    worker->moveToThread(&m_thread);

    connect(&m_thread, &QThread::finished, worker, &QObject::deleteLater);

    connect(this, &PieChart::registerCallback, worker, &PieChartWorker::registerCallback);
    connect(worker, &PieChartWorker::response, this, &PieChart::response);
    m_thread.start();
}

void PieChart::response(const QString question, const QByteArray& answer, QJSValue callback)
{
    if (callback.isCallable()) {
        QJSValueList args;
        args << question;
        args << QString::fromLocal8Bit(answer);
        callback.call(args);
    }
}
```

app.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Charts 1.0

Item {
    width: 300; height: 200
    Text {
        id: label
        text: "hello"
        x:100; y:100
        color: 'black'
    }
    PieChart {
        anchors.center: parent
        width: 100; height: 100

        Component.onCompleted: {
            registerCallback(updateResult)
        }

        function updateResult(question, answer) {
            console.log(question)
            console.log(answer)
            label.text = answer
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Holy moly what are you doing here, start again my friend. Emit a signal `response` from the C++ of the PieChart and then simply use the auto-generated QML signal handler `onResponse:` to execute some Javascript. As soon as you think you need to use any QJS classes, you immediately know that the approach is incorrect.

Comment: I think also it would be useful to provide the header files, even if they are simple. It will allow us to compile and modify your code.

Comment: The code is based off from the example app from QT pie chart http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-tutorials-extending-qml-example.html.

The reason why i did'nt want to use onResponse is that, there is a requirement where can register a javascript function as a callback within QML.

Comment: It is not recommended to use QJSValue, there are virtually no Qt examples suggesting the use of QJSValue in user code. Why can't you call your JS function from the QML signal handler instead, e.g onResponse? Signal slots are provided to you as a way of avoiding callback functions.

Comment: the call to `invokeMethod` calls `responseInternal` of the PieChartWorker object, and so even though are you are using a QueuedConnection, `responseInternal` will still be called in the PieChartWorker thread, and so will the `respsonse` method, and the `updateResponse` callback. If you don't believe it, set the objectName property on each of your threads, and print it out with qDebug(), you will see that everything is occuring in the PieChartWorker and that is likely to cause instability

Comment: I tried putting a breakpoint under PieChart::response, the thread is in the main thread, not in the PieChartWorker thread.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on this question for several hours, and finally, I resolved it.

**First.** JS function has an concept like `context`, and your callback use `label`, which is an outer UI Object. 
So when it was invoked from C++, the JS Engine doesn't known what is `label`, because the `context` changed.

you can declare the callback like this(bind the callback with root):

```
Item{
    id: root
    function reload() {
        X.send(request, root.callback)
    }
    function callback(data) {
        console.log(data, root)
    }
}
```

**Second.** If you modify the UI property in the callback, you must make sure that it was invoked in main loop. like `label.text=...`, you must do it in main loop.

You can use `QCoreApplication::postEvent` to invoke the QJSValue in the main loop.